# How to link a new folder to git repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am new to git and I am working on a project. So below are the steps I followed. I went online created a git repo. And then in desktop I opened the Git CMD and linked that repo to my `Brand new empty project folder` and then kept on developing and using code

```
1. git add  
2. git commit -m "some comment
3. git push
```

till now everything is good.

**Issue:** I want to switch to a different desktop but obviously my original project will not be there, So what is the process I need to follow get all the files to a new folder in my new system. Also, when I make a new changes Git should take only the new change as the change set and not the entire project. I mean how to make sure I get the entire already developed code to a new folder and still act like that it's the original folder where the whole project was developed so that if I make change Git should only detect those as new change.

**End Result** if I run Git Status command in my new folder I should get result as `Your local folder is in sync with master and no changelist detected` something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `git clone` and `git pull` commands.

> git clone - Clone a repository into a new directory

Documentation available [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

> git pull - Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch

Documentation available [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).

If you're looking for a tutorial with more details about the basic git commands then [this is a good one](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository).

Comment: So, firstly I should create a new folder, and then use git init. and then run above two commands? or folder and all will be created automatically. I just need to run above two commads mentioned by you at the right location? Please guide me step wise as I am beginner

Comment: In your question you mentioned that you're already pushing changes to a remote repository. "git clone <repository-url>" will make your remote repository available on your local machine. In the folder where you run that command, a new folder (with the name of your repository) will appear and contain everything that you pushed before. There's no need to run git init anymore. If after that you push new changes from your first machine, then a "git pull" on your second machine will make those changes also available there.

Comment: I've also edited the post and added a link to a git tutorial that demonstrates the basic commands. If you run through that, things should become clear(er).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. Worked like a charm. And thanks for explaining the git-pull in your comment section.